# Binding non constant reference to temporary object - An example where it can happen

Tags: c++

The common knowledge is that **non constant references cannot be bound to temporary objects** (cannot prolong its lifetime). The problem is that **the following program compiles without even a warning**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Type
{
    int m;
    Type b() {
        Type ret = {1};
        return ret;
    }
    Type& c() {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Type a;
    Type &obj = a.b().c(); // b() returns a temporary and c() a reference to that!
    std::cout << obj.m << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

b() returns a temporary and c() a reference to that! How is [this](http://ideone.com/uS8FPl) possible ?

PS : The fact that it compiles buffles me more than the fact that it outputs a correct result; It is totally understandable that the memory where the temporary used to live may be unharmed until it's used.

Comment: Sure you can: `extern int f(); int && r = f();`

Comment: That's an rvalue reference

Comment: So what, rvalue references are references too. Or are you some kind of reference racist?

Comment: obj should be a bad reference, if it appears sensible it's only by accident.

Comment: @KerrekSB Categorization is not discrimination, especially in knowledge

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're using Microsofts compiler, binding temporaries to non const references is allowed as a language extension.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Fine, but then your opening sentence is plain wrong, as I demonstrated. Moreover, it's doubly wrong, because it conflates binding of references with lifetime extension, which are two separate issues, as you demonstrated yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The term "temporary" refers to the return value of a function call expression `f()` where `f` is declared as `T f();` and `T` is a non-reference object type. Clearly, your call expression `a.b().c()` is not a temporary, since the declared return type of `c` is a reference type.

No temporary object is created *for the purpose of evaluating the function call*.

The fact that `c` is a member function that is itself evaluated on a temporary is immaterial. (But of course your code produces a dangling reference; it's undefined behaviour to evaluate `obj`.)

---

(The right place to address your concern is to *qualify the member functions*, e.g. `Type & c() &`, etc., to ensure that the instance argument itself is an lvalue.)